# How use DATE_ADD in Yii $criteria?

Tags: php, yii

Model.php

```
// Declare $datetime_limit
public datetime_limit;
```

Controller.php

```
// datetime_limit should be the actual datetime + 5 days
$criteria->select="DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 DAY) AS datetime_limit";
```

Error Message:

```
Active record "Users" is trying to select an invalid column "DATE_ADD(NOW()". Note, the column must exist in the table or be an expression with alias.
```

---

Edit 1:

I would like to filter the find w/ a condition using a relation table (Many to Many).
So the `datetime_limit` cannot have in relational `events.datetime`.
How can I do that?

```
$criteria->select=array("DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 DAY) AS datetime_limit");
$criteria->with=array('events');
$criteria->having='datetime_limit!=`events`.`datetime`';
$models=Users::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Comment: When `CDbCriteria::$select` is a string, Yii splits it on each comma. Try passing this expression as an array with a single element in it (`$criteria->select = array('DATE_ADD(...) AS datetime_limit');`.

Comment: @DCoder Post as an answer, please. :)

Comment: [Enable DB query/param logging](https://gist.github.com/4420192) and see what query gets generated. It might be a difference between `having` and `where`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This exception is thrown in [`CActiveFinder::getColumnSelect`](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.12/framework/db/ar/CActiveFinder.php#L885).

When `CDbCriteria::$select` is a string, it's treated as a simple list of comma-delimited columns. Your expression gets interpreted as two distinct columns. You can work around this by setting `select` to an array yourself - in this case the comma splitting is not done<sup>1</sup>:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->select = array("DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 DAY) AS datetime_limit");
$models = Users::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Note that if you write an alias that doesn't correspond to a public model property or a DB field, it will be retrieved but silently ignored - for some reason Yii doesn't throw an exception for that.

---

<sup>1</sup> However, this function will still attempt to find a `.` in the expression and interpret the part after it as a column identifier - don't use `.` in your expression and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks, it helped me a lot! If I want to use the custom field `datetime_limit` in $criteria->condition, how should I do that? Im getting `SQL: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'datetime_limit' in 'where clause'.`.

Comment: @LucianoNascimento: Your criteria has to select some expression aliased to `datetime_limit`, otherwise MySQL won't know what `datetime_limit` means...

Comment: @LucianoNascimento Add the `datetime_limit` comparison to the having criteria. That is, `$criteria->having = 'datetime_limit > somecolumnorvalue`, as an example.