# How use DATE_ADD in Yii $criteria especially inside select?

Tags: php, yii

My code for this sql part is

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
.......
$criteria->select = 'user.user_id as userId, user.name as userName, COUNT(*) AS totalCount,
                        SUM(CASE WHEN (t.create_datetime > (SELECT DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL(2-DAYOFWEEK(curdate())) DAY)) AND t.create_datetime < \'2013-06-08\') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS weeklyCount,
                        SUM(CASE WHEN (MONTH(t.create_datetime) = 9 ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS monthlyCount';
.......
$criteria->group = 'user.user_id';
$criteria->with = array('user');
$criteria->addCondition('t.deleted=0', 'AND');
$criteria->addCondition('t.user_id = user.user_id', 'AND');
```

THe error I got is:

```
Type: CDbException
Active record `Inspection` is trying to select an invalid column `SUM(CASE WHEN (t.create_datetime > (SELECT DATE_ADD(curdate()`. Note, the column must exist in the table or be an expression with alias.
```

I have took a look at : [How use DATE_ADD in Yii $criteria?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14059514/how-use-date-add-in-yii-criteria) which is a solution for `date_add` in Yii `$criteria`. But in my case date add is not for select, it is a condition in select.

Please help me. Thanks

Comment: do you still have the problem after trying davey solution?

Comment: I'm trying. Because I'm dealing with another problem. But I think his solution is ok. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an array of the select statement, this way Yii can "recognize" the aliases (if `$criteria->select` is a string, it doesn't know where to look for the aliases):

```
$criteria->select = array(
   'user.user_id AS userId', 
   'user.name AS userName', 
   'COUNT(*) AS totalCount',
   'SUM(CASE WHEN (t.create_datetime > (SELECT DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL(2-DAYOFWEEK(curdate())) DAY)) AND t.create_datetime < \'2013-06-08\') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS weeklyCount',
   'SUM(CASE WHEN (MONTH(t.create_datetime) = 9 ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS monthlyCount'
);
```

Comment: I don't know why after put array to it, some field can not be showed.

Comment: userName, monthlyCount, totalCount. But I think it's not bc of adding array. Bc when I separate from 1 select to many select ( such as $criteria->select = 'user.user_id AS userId'; $criteria->select = 'user.name AS userName'), it can not show some fields also.

Comment: Did you add the aliases as properties in your model?

Comment: I have added all of aliases in model before, but don't know why it's not showed. I have solved it in a different way.